# Progress bar on a button click

Tags: android, onclick, progress-bar

In my app, at the click of a button, the app does some processing, sends some data over the network and then stops. As it takes some time, I tried putting in a progress bar. The code for the progress bar is at the beginning of the onclick listener for the button. After the progress bar code, the processing and sending data over the network takes place. 
But the progress bar is not visible at all. Do I need to necessarily show the progress bar in a separate thread?

This is what i have used to show the progress bar

```
final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pd.setMessage("Please wait..");
pd.setCancelable(true);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the AsyncTask class which was used to do process in background and you can also showing up your progressbar there

Here is the simple snippet of code for AsyncTask

```
class BackgroundProcess extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
   private ProgressDialog progress;
   public doInBackground(Void...arg){
        publishProgress();
        // do your processing here like sending data or downloading etc.
   }
   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "Wait...");       
   }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(progress!=null)
        progress.dismiss();
    progress = null;
   }
}
```

now initialize and execute it in button onclick listener like this way

```
new BackgroundProcess().execute();
```

now progressdialog will be publish and appear on the screen and when process was completed then from the onPostExecute() just dismiss the progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into my application, and it works just fine. Are you calling all of that from the UI Thread? If you are doing some heavy processing and data transmission, make sure not to run that on the UI thread. Make an AsyncTask to handle the network stuff.

EDIT: I moved it into its own thread, and it no longer works, so make sure it's being called from the UI Thread.

Comment: Yes..I am doing all the work from the UI thread itself..and there is a lot of data transfer over the network that takes place..So I guess, I would have to make and AsyncTask to achieve the work..Thanks